# Find Exact Match in one Column and return text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula that could do the following for me:

I have my Column A showing either "In" or "Out", then I have a series of unique numbers in Column B, Column C I have some numbers gotten from Column B. I would like to find a formula where I could key in Column D.

This formula should first, find out if Column A is "In" or "Out", if Column A is "In", then search through the whole of Column C to see if the number in Column B has appeared in Column C or not,  If it has, return Sold in the cell in Column D.

I tried with `IF`, `VLOOKUP` and `Match` function but could not find a suitable combination. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This seems like a typical `COUNTIF` or 'COUNTIFS` query.

Comment: yes, possible, but I have no idea how to apply it in this context. Possible to advise?

Comment: See the answer below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should achieve the desired output:

`=IF(A2="In",IF(COUNTIF(C:C,B2)>1,"Sold","Unsold"),"")`

Then click and drag it down for the rest of the records.

Comment: That's exactly my thoughts. You could refrain from checking for larger than 1 though. It can just be `IF(COUNTIF(C:C,B2),`

Comment: @JvdV Thanks to both of you!! I tried and it works for the whole spreadsheet, but i'm just wondering why the formula did not work for the first cell, which is D2?

Comment: Confirm that the referencing in cell D2 is correct, in that it is lining up properly with cells A2, and B2.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This formula is so useful :))